# mysql_connect() causing web page to crash

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am currently running an amazon EC2 instance to host my website.  I am trying to connect to the MySQL database.

I have code ...

```
<h1>Test page</h1>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("xxx.xxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com","username","password");
?>
```

An attempt to load this web page will cause an infinite loading symbol.  It is as if an infinite loop is running.  Here are some details ...

1. The page will load if i remove the `mysql_connect()` function
2. The page will properly display all php data including all other functions.
3. The "host","username" and "password" arguments are **correct** and the MySQL database server is **running**.  I know this because i can connect and manipulate it through Sequel Pro.
4. The page will load if i modify the "host" argument to something incorrect.

Feel free to ask questions.  Thanks.

EDIT: After waiting about 90 seconds, the page will eventually load and display error 2002.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
mysqli_connect()
```

instead of

```
mysql_connect()
```

So maybe this server only supports mysqli.
I'm not sure what else to try if everything else is right.

Comment: Changing it to mysqli_connect() causes the same problem.  The page will infinitely load as if something has crashed.

Comment: Are you sure this server's api allows this type of access? Does it ever timeout? Or just constantly load? Let it go until the page timeouts and see if you can get an error.

Comment: Try using echo mysqli_error($connection);
Also before that type this in your connection mysqli_connect() or die("could not connect to sql"); To see if that error is displayed.

Comment: These are a few steps of troubleshooting.

Comment: Attempting.  Will get back to you in a moment.

Comment: After waiting about 90 seconds, it appears the page finally loads where i get error 2002.  Will look into it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the server is not responding to the request you sent and so mysql connection is not being established. Try using another server.